# Add custom tags to raven

Tags: python, logging, sentry, raven

How to add custom tags to get raven set it to sentry?

When I used raven in django there was several tags like OS, Browser, etc.

But I want to add such tags by myself using raven, without django.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding the question, you can pass to sentry whatever you want in `extra` dictionary, see [raven docs](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#usage).

You can also construct messages via `capture*` methods (and pass `extra` too):

- [capture](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=capture#raven.Client.capture)
- [captureException](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=capture#raven.Client.captureException)
- [captureMessage](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=capture#raven.Client.captureMessage)
- [captureQuery](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=capture#raven.Client.captureQuery)

Btw, OS, browser...etc parameters sentry gets from the passed `request` object.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. Just use Client.capture

```
from raven import Client
client = Client("https://<key>:<secret>@sentry.io/<project>")
client.capture("raven.events.Message", message='foo_bar', data={
    'tags': {
        'tag_name': "tag_value"
    }
})
```